# What are good strategies for handling Option - Some(null) in F#

Tags: .net, f#, option-type

I am new to the F# language and encountered exceptions when pattern matching Some and None using an Option type with a string value. This was discovered using FSCheck. Given a (string option) property type, a null reference exception is thrown when the value of the string assigned is null, resulting in a value = Some(null). My expectation (wrongly) is that this would result in a None. The naïve approach was to check Some and None, and in the case of Some, add a subsequent match to handle Some(null). The slightly less naïve approach I used was (match Option.ofObj optValue with …). This seems counterintuitive as I would have to repeat this pattern everywhere I am dealing with an Option type with a value that could be assigned null.

The type used

```
type LoanApplication =
{ Name: string
  Age: int
  CreditScore: int option
  Website: string option
  Email: string option
  PhoneNumber: string option }
```

The function that throws the null ref at match input with

```
    member this.processApplication(application: LoanApplication) =
    //we want to create a person
    //do we have a valid application
    let getValidRequest (input: string option) =
        match input with
        | None -> IsUrl false
        | Some optValue ->
                let isUrl = optValue.StartsWith("http://")
                let isEmail = optValue.ToString().Contains("@")
                let isPhone = optValue.ToString().StartsWith("+")

                match isUrl, isEmail, isPhone with
                | true, _, _ -> IsUrl true
                | _, true, _ -> IsEmail true
                | _, _, true -> IsPhone true
                | _ -> IsUrl false


    let validateTypeFields (application: LoanApplication) =
        match (getValidRequest application.Email), (getValidRequest application.PhoneNumber) with
        | IsEmail true, IsPhone true ->
            Valid
                { Name = application.Name
                  Age = application.Age
                  CreditScore = application.CreditScore
                  Website = application.Website
                  Email = application.Email.Value
                  PhoneNumber = application.PhoneNumber.Value }
        | _ -> Invalid application


    let validationResult = validateTypeFields application

    match validationResult with
    | Valid validApplication -> ProspectiveApplication validApplication
    | Invalid application -> InvalidApplication application
```

The test setup calling the function that fails (Note: FSCheck is what was assigning the Some(null) its included in the setup to clarify the problem.

```
    [<Fact>]
member this.IsTheTestThatIsFailing() =
    let application: LoanApplication =
        { Name = "Joe"
          Age = 30
          CreditScore = Some(700)
          Website = Some("http://www.google.com")
          Email = Some(null)
          PhoneNumber = Some("+123456789") }

    let processor = new ApplicantProcess()
    let result = processor.processApplication application

    match result with
    | ValidApplication validApplication
    | ProspectiveApplication validApplication -> Assert.True(false)
    | InvalidApplication application -> Assert.True(true)
```

What are some of the correct ways of handling Option(null) or preventing them in the first place?
In my example case, I want a property with a string value that cannot be assigned null.

Comment: Please show us some example code.

Comment: Added example code

Comment: Unfortunately F#, which we all want to be safer than C# and .NET in this area, has ended up somewhat worse than C# with its new non-nullable feature. I've been hoping for years that this would be improved, but no such luck thus far. You will have to check for null strings at the input boundary, and decide how to handle them.

Comment: If you want to do further modelling, you could have domain types for phone, email and website, rather than string option. Usage of primitive can turn into anti-pattern called "primitive obsession", and F# allows you to easily define your own domain types. I recommend "Domain modelling made simple: Functions and Values - Isaac Abraham" session:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9D20fKx45xI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Until F# gets [nullable reference type support](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-design/blob/main/RFCs/FS-1060-nullable-reference-types.md) which matches C# 8 feature, you can use an active pattern to make it convenient:

```ml
let (|IsNullOrEmptyString|IsNonEmptyString|) x =
  if System.String.IsNullOrEmpty x then
    IsNullOrEmptyString
  else
    IsNonEmptyString x
```

and adjust your code

```ml
match input with
| None | Some IsNullOrEmptyString -> IsUrl false
| ... // rest of your code
```

It adds the bonus for checking for empty string, but it is up to you, to define the relevant active pattern for your domain logic.

Comment: Being new to F# this begs the question... Should Options be used for string at all since we are going to have to check null values?

Comment: note: you can also define an active pattern that would work on the `string option` type itself, I think the answer should highlight enough for you to try it out.

@JorgeCuervolini yes option should be used for reference types that may be null, until the nullable reference type support comes, at which point, it will be matter of choice.

Comment: As from F# guidelines, nulls should be checked at an early stage and you should fail fast, then don't give any meaning to null strings in your logic, use options for that.

Answer (score 1):

You're in a bind, in a good way. When you unwrap a variable and apply a function to that unwrapped value which in turn returns a new wrapped value, you are logically dealing with a [bind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)#Bind) combinator.

To demonstrate this, let's employ an active pattern, similar to that in the answer of [smoothdeveloper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76899154).

```
let checkNullOrEmpty s =
    if System.String.IsNullOrEmpty s then None
    else Some s

let (|CheckNullOrEmpty|_|) = Option.bind checkNullOrEmpty

match input with
| None | CheckNullOrEmpty _ -> IsUrl false
| Some url -> ... // rest of your code
```

It may be possible to refactor and make the chaining of `Option.bind` explicit:

```
Some "url"  // acquire url as option - might fail
|> Option.bind checkNullOrEmpty
|> Option.bind (fun url -> ...) // rest of your code, assuming the next step might fail as well
```

If you're feeling adventurous you can shorten the resulting code by providing the `bind` operator.

```
let (>>=) ma f = Option.bind f ma

Some "url"  // acquire url as option
>>= checkNullOrEmpty
>>= fun url -> ... // rest of your code
```